# All 3 value combinations of a list without duplicates

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to get all possible 3 value combinations out of something like:

```
stuff = ['1', '2', '3']
```

But in such a way to only have each value represented once, I.E:

> 123
>
> 132
>
> 213
>
> 231
>
> 321
>
> 312

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Check the `itertools` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can try this:-

```
import itertools
a = ['1','2','3']
for i in itertools.permutations(a):
    print(''.join(i))
```